# Pandas how to loop through a MultiIndex series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiIndex series look like this:

```
user_id  cookie  browser
1        1_1     [chrome45]
2        2_1     [IE 7]
2        2_2     [IE 7, IE 8]
```

There are two levels to this MultiIndex, `user_id` and `cookie`. The value is the browser.

What I want to do is to count the number of times a user uses a different browser.

So for user 1 in this case, he only used 1 browser. But for user 2, he used three browsers (IE7 appeared twice under different cookies, so I count it twice instead of once)

How can I loop through it and get a result like this:

```
r = defaultdict(int)

for user_id in multiIndex_series:
    for cookie in multiIndex_series[user_id]:
        r[user_id] += len(multiIndex_series[user_id][cookie]) # I don't know how to get user_id out of the MultiIndex series
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with apply lambda function where get `length` of flatten `lists` - see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/2901002) for more info:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id':[1,2,2],
                   'cookie':['1_1','2_1','2_2'],
                   'browser':[['chrome45'],['IE 7'],['IE 7','IE 8']]})
df = df.set_index(['user_id','cookie'])
print (df)
                     browser
user_id cookie              
1       1_1       [chrome45]
2       2_1           [IE 7]
        2_2     [IE 7, IE 8]

from  itertools import chain
print (df.groupby(level='user_id')['browser']
         .apply(lambda x: len(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))))
user_id
1    1
2    3
Name: browser, dtype: int64
```

Instead `lambda` is possible use custom function `f` what is better way for testing:

```
def f(x):
    print (list(chain.from_iterable(x)))
    return len(list(chain.from_iterable(x)))

['chrome45']
['IE 7', 'IE 7', 'IE 8']

print (df.groupby(level='user_id')['browser'].apply(f))
user_id
1    1
2    3
Name: browser, dtype: int64
```

---

If need loop in series, one possible solution is:

```
for user_id, val in df['browser'].iteritems():
    print (user_id)
    print (val)

['chrome45']
(2, '2_1')
['IE 7']
(2, '2_2')
['IE 7', 'IE 8']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! The part that I don't quite get is the `x` in `chain.from_iterable(x)`.  What is `x` in this case? I tried printing out `x` and I can see it is the entire group. How does `chain.from_iterable` pick out the `browser` column specifically? (because of the `groupby(...)['browser']` part? )

Comment: If use `df.groupby(level='user_id')['browser']` and then apply some function, then in each loop is in `x` variable df['browser'] per group. The best is test it in `f` function by `def f(x): print (x)`

Comment: I almost did this `for user_id in multiIndex.series.index.level[0] for cookie in multiIndex.series[userid]`. Thanks for saving me :)

Comment: Yes, but loop in pandas are obviosly slow, so better is avoid them. see perfect [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002) - `Jeff` is now developer of pandas.